# Is it possible to get all the object with the attribute having the max value in JMES Path?

Tags: javascript, json, jmespath

*(Some precision: I want a solution in full JMES Path, so I don't want to use javascript or other language to store variable)*

If for example I have a simple object like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "att1":12,
      "att2":"name1"
   },
   {  
      "att1":15,
      "att2":"name2"
   },
   {  
      "att1":15,
      "att2":"name3"
   },
   {  
      "att1":11,
      "att2":"name4"
   }
]
```

If I use `max_by` function here like this: `max_by(@,&att1)`, it would give me this result:

```
{
   "att1": 15,
   "att2": "name2"
}
```

In this case there is only one object, but we can see that there is at least 2 object with the max value in `att1`. So I tried this code: `@[?att1 == max_by(@,&att1)]` but it give me an error. I don't know why, so the questions are:

1. Firstly, is it possible to do it(with any way and any tools) in JMES
   Path ?
2. Lastly, if it's possible, how to do it ?

EDIT: I think it's a type problem. For example, if I use this code `` type(`4`) `` it return `"number"`, but if I use this code `type(4)` or `type(to_number(4))` it give me an error

EDIT2: Strangly if I try this: `` max_by(@,&att1).att1 == `15` `` it return `true`, but when I do this:
`@[?att1 == max_by(@,&att1)]` it return an error. I checked type too, and this `max_by(@,&att1).att1` is a number, so normally there is no type error I think...

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter by a number, the number must be surrounded by [`back ticks`](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#id9)

```js
var arr = [{"att1":12,"att2":"name1"},{"att1":15,"att2":"name2"},{"att1":15,"att2":"name3"},{"att1":11,"att2":"name4"}]

let maxAtt1 = jmespath.search(arr, "max_by(@,&att1).att1")

console.log(jmespath.search(arr, "[?att1 == `" + maxAtt1 + "`]"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jmespath/0.15.0/jmespath.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's a good answer but you need to get out of JMES Path language and return to it. I want to do it in FULL JMES Path, I'm sorry if I don't precise it, I will asap. But my question is: is there a way to define variable in JMES PATH ? It could be very usefull in this case.